# What does packet boundary flag do in L2cap in Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

What is the use of packet boundary flag in L2CAP in Bluetooth.
And it also has concept of automatically Flushable, Non-automatically Flushable and Point-to-point. What does it mean?
Please answer the question, It would be great help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The packet boundary flag is part of the fragmentation and reassembly mechanism which allows L2CAP to transfer data units that are larger than the payload in the physical packets sent over the air.

I suggest you read about the HCI ACL data packet format, you can find it in the Bluetooth core specification which is freely available from the Bluetooth SIG website https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification/